# emu8086 does not support the int 14h BIOS serial port API

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I'm having trouble coding in assembly using emu8086. The error will display when `INT 14h` is used.

Questions :

1. is there a way to configure the emu8086 vector table.
2. is there another assembly emulator supports `INT 14h`.

[image: A screenshot of emu8086]

Comment: Bochs, QEMU, DosBox can emulate serial ports and their BIOSes support `int 14h` if correctly configured. As far as I know EMU8086 doesn't have any support for `int 14h`

Comment: According to the screenshot, the usual mechanisms for installing your own interrupt handlers work.  `SIDT [m32]` stores the address of the IDT.  I guess you'd then put the segment part into a segment register, and use the other part as an address, and index into the table to set your own entries.

Comment: There are very few redeeming features in Int14, programs that use it very rarely operate correctly if they are ever run on real hardware.  Serial ports need an hardware interrupt handler to prevent data loss, the BIOS doesn't.

Comment: @PeterCordes : EMU8086 only supports 8086 instruction set so _SIDT_ is unavailable. You generally turn off interrupts, update the interrupt vector table directly setting both the segment and offset words (using `mov` instructions.) and then re-enable interrupts.